# Increment or decrement with specific value php

Tags: php

I have a problem that i can't solved it with php. the problem is let's say in example.

a vehicle has 10 fuel liter that decrease a liter every 100Km. the place it want to go is 1000Km.

so how to decrement with 100 value instead 1 default?

`for(;$length>0;$length--){echo $length;}`

thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: $length - 100? a standard subtraction, pretty basic maths

Comment: @user3263978 and your attempted answer: This won´t work. Do you mean `-=` instead of `-` ? And `--` is a special case, there is no `---` or `----` etc.

Comment: damien: thx, it's not make sense to me.
3263: may u answer it in code php?

Comment: i tried this code so far but it doesn't work.

<code>
$lenght=1000-100;
$fuel=10-1;

for($lenght>0;$lenght--){echo $length}</code>

Comment: @user3644914: Well of course. 1000-100 is 900 and will stay 900. You need to substract from the current value $length. And please read a beginners book.

Comment: @user3644914 and your edit: Makes no sense...

Comment: so what the completely code to work?

Answer (score 0):

This code: `$length--` means take the value of length use it and then decrement it, it's called post decrement, `--$length` this instead means first decrement it and the use it, it's called pre decrement. 
To solve your problem you could use one of these syntax:

```
$length -= 100;
$length = $length - 100;
```

CODE:

```
$fuel=10; 
for($length=1000;$length>0;$length -= 100){
    echo "len: ".$length;
    echo " fuel: ".$fuel--;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: i get error undefined variabel.

$length -= 100;
$fuel=10;

for(;$length>0;--$length){echo $length.'<br>';}

Comment: you need to inizialize the variable
for ($length = 10000000;$length > 0; $length-=100) {
    echo $length."<br>";

Comment: thanks it work, but how about fuel object? every 100km decrease a liter?